# Orchard CMS. IAutofacActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, orchardcms, autofac

I need to inject services into WebApi Action Filter (or into DelegatingHandler).
With Autofac I can use IAutofacActionFilter (https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration). But there isn't Autofac's WebApi Dependecy Resolver in the Orchard. There is Orchard's resolver implementation.

Also I tried this:

```
var service = (IMyService)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IMyService));
or
var service = (IMyService)request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IMyService));
```

But it doesn't work too.